# Spree 3.1: Increment Order number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I am trying to make Order number incremental in Spree 3.1.

I got only this:

```
Spree::Order.class_eval do
  before_validation(on: :create) do
    self.number = Spree::Core::NumberGenerator.new(prefix: 'S').send(:generate_permalink, Spree::Order)
  end
end
```

but it's only change prefix.

How should I rewrite `new_candidate` to get right result?

```
#lib/spree/core/number_generator.rb
def new_candidate(length)
    @prefix + length.times.map { @candidates.sample(random: @random) }.join
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def new_candidate(host)
  max_number = host.maximum(:number) || STARTING_NUMBER
  @prefix + (max_number.gsub(@prefix, '').to_i + 1).to_s
end

def generate_permalink(host)
  new_candidate(host)
end
```

You will need to define STARTING_NUMBER constant in the generator class. Also, you will not need the `@length` instance variable anymore.

Comment: It works perfect but now I got problem to override whole NumberGenerator module in app without touching gem.

Comment: You can use `class_eval` on the generator class in file lib/spree/core/number_generator_decorator.rb. Also make sure lib folder is autoloaded by placing this is in config/application.rb: `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')`

Comment: It finally works I had to put `Spree::Core::NumberGenerator.class_eval` inside `app/models/spree/core/number_generator_decorator.rb`

Answer (score 0):

I recently worked on a similar task to have an order number that contains the date of the order + a randomly generated number (for uniqueness).

To achieve this I add an `order_decorator.rb` into `models/spree` and I override the `generate_number` method:

```
// First i redefine the length for my random number
NUMBER_LENGTH  = 5

def generate_number(options = {})
    options[:length]  ||= NUMBER_LENGTH

    date = Date.today.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
    possible = (0..9).to_a
    random = "-#{(0...options[:length]).map { possible.shuffle.first }.join}"
    self.number ||= date + random
  end
```

I don't like the generation of the random number (I would use `SecureRandom for it) but i left it initially was in Spree because for this it will do fine for my needs.

In your case you can add inside the method the code you need to make your number incremental.

I hope this helps!

Cheers

Comment: In Spree 3.1 there is no method `generate_number` in Spree::Order model or am I wrong?